# What is the difference between .addEventListener and .on() when adding an event in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a `listener` to my modal to be able to apply a behavior every time the modal is opened.

According to the Bootstrap 5 documentation, you could use:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events

```js
const myModalEl = document.getElementById('fast-modal')
myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
  // do something...
})
```

[image]

My HTML of the modal is:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="fast-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-complement" id="fast-result-box"></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using pure Javascript, it works as expected!

---

My problem is when I try to do the same event addition using Jquery 3.6, like this:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#fast-modal', function () {
    alert('hi');
})
        
// or

$('#fast-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('xx');
})
```

Why when I use Jquery it doesn't work? Where is the error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think you had an error in your markup. You needed a button to toggle your bootstrap modal and moreover you omitted to include the script and stylesheet for bootstrap 5.
First of all you need to include your Jquery library and after the loading of that you have to include your bootstrap library.

Both ways are properly functioning in the snippet I have attached here.
I hope that helps you.

```js
const myModalEl = document.getElementById('fast-modal')
myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
  alert("hello!!");
})

$('#fast-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('xx');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#fast-modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="fast-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="fastModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="fastModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

But, in my production code, I already have all the bootstrap includes and all the buttons that act inside the modal and I'm calling the respective functions after loading the page as you mentioned... even so, it still doesn't work !

Maybe there's some other factor that I'm not finding but, your points brought up, they all exist in my production code.